# Cannot connect to postgresql via php pdo on docker-compose

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, docker-compose

I cannot connect my php app via PDO to postgresql. I have the classic error :

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But I can connect to my database with DBeaver for example via the same config I use for PDO (same host, same port, same user and same password !) and I can see the postgresql connexion with netstat commande.

I use docker via docker-compose. This is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - "${WWW_DIR}:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro"
      - "${NGINX_LOG}:/var/log/nginx"
      - "${NGINX_DIR}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:80"

  php:
    build: ${PHP_DIR}
    container_name: php
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
      - composer
    volumes:
      - "${PHP_LOG}/access.log:/var/log/access.log"
      - "${PHP_LOG}/error.log:/var/log/error.log"
      - "${WWW_DIR}:/var/www/html"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}

  composer:
    restart: 'no'
    image: composer
    command: install
    volumes:
      - "${WWW_DIR}:/app"

  pgsql:
    restart: always
    build: ${PGSQL_DIR}
    container_name: pgsql
    volumes:
      - "${PGSQL_DIR}/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
      - "${PGSQL_LOG}:${POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR}:z"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR=${POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR}
```

This is my .env file :

```
# DIRs
WWW_DIR=../html
PHP_DIR=./php
NGINX_DIR=./nginx
PGSQL_DIR=./pgsql

# LOGs
NGINX_LOG=./nginx/log
PHP_LOG=./php/log
PGSQL_LOG=./pgsql/log
POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR=/var/log/pgsql

# DB
POSTGRES_USER=site
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=etis
POSTGRES_DB=dbname
```

And this is my Dockerfile for postgresql :

```
FROM postgres:alpine

# DB import
COPY db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

So what I mistake ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application runs inside a container and when it tries to connect to 127.0.0.1 then it expects the database server to run in the same container. And that is not the case. Your database runs in the container/service `pgsql`.

When you run your application on the host it works because everything runs on the same machine. Also your database client works because you map the same port on the host.

**SOLUTION:**

Change the reference to the database server in your application to point to `pgsql` instead of `127.0.0.1`. To have the same working on host as well you can add the mapping to /etc/hosts as well (or the equivalent for Windows). Since you use an environment file, putting the database URL in there is even a better solution. You can do that once you have it working with the hardcoded value.

Comment: Oh yeah ! Now you say that it's so obvious ! I'm feeling stupid... Thank you !